# How do I create an object in JavaScript, that dynamically creates a div (with style properties and an id) and appends to my html page?

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, appendchild

I'm trying to create an object in javascript that will dynamically create a line with style properties, and attach it to my page. I've seen other solutions that just create an element, but none that can be nicely fit into a single object.

Here's the code I'm trying:

```js
function line(pos_x, pos_y, length, width, color, num) {
 this = document.createElement('div');
    this.style.left = pos_x + "%";
 this.style.top = pos_y + "%";
 this.style.length = length + "%";
 this.style.width = width + "%";
 this.style.backgroundColor = color;
    this.id = "line" + num;
    document.appendChild(this);
}

var line1 = line(10, 0, 100, 100, #2ecc71, 1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't set `this`

http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/

Also, there is `style.width`, but no length property

To be visible, the div needs `style.height > 0px`

```js
function line(pos_x, pos_y, thickness, width, color, num) {
 var line = document.createElement('div');
    line.style.left = pos_x + "%";
 line.style.top = pos_y + "%";
 line.style.height = thickness + "px";
 line.style.width = width + "%";
 line.style.backgroundColor = color;
    line.id = "line" + num;
    document.appendChild(line);
    return line;
}

var line1 = line(10, 0, 10, 100, #2ecc71, 1);
```

Comment: One thing - if I set line = document.createElement('div'); and then use line.someAttribute = someValue; am I not creating another element because I'm use the variable line again?

Comment: no, you're just setting an attribute of the object line